# For the adjoint $A$ and any nontrivial representation $R$, why is $R$ in $R \otimes A$?

Tags: representation-theory

For any nontrivial representation $R$ of a Lie group $G$, I think it's true that 
$$R \subset R \otimes A$$
where $A$ is the adjoint representation. I've checked this for a few simple cases.

In terms of the physicists' notation with tensors, this is true for the following reason. Let the fundamental representation be represented by a rank 1 tensor with an upper index, and let the dual representation have a lower index. The adjoint representation is the traceless part of their product (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235583/why-is-bf-n-otimes-bar-bf-n-cong-bf-1-oplus-textthe-adjoint-represent)) so it has one upper and one lower index. Now if we tensor this with any representation $R$, we can recover the index structure of $R$ by contracting anything, e.g.
$$A^i_j R^{kl}_m \supset A^i_j R^{jl}_m$$
has the index structure of the $R$ representation: two upper, one lower.

How would a mathematician prove this statement? Is there a simple and elegant reason this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is there a simple and elegant reason this is true?*

Sure, I think so. I'm going to work at the level of Lie algebras and assume $R$ is irreducible. We identify the adjoint representation, as a vector space, with the Lie algebra itself, and consider the action map $$A \otimes R \longrightarrow R \quad \text{given by} \quad x \otimes v \longmapsto x(v),$$ where $x(v)$ denotes the action of the element $x$ of the Lie algebra $A$ on the vector $v$ in the representation $R$. This is a homomorphism of representations$^{[1]}$, which is non-zero if $R$ is non-trivial. Thus $R$ is canonically a quotient of $A \otimes R$.

It follows (at least for finite dimensional representations of compact Lie groups, or in any situation where the representation $A \otimes R$ is semisimple) that $R$ is (perhaps non-canonically) a subobject of $A \otimes R$.

[1] Proof (in case you are interested): For $x,y \in A$ and $v \in R$ we have
$$y(x \otimes v)=\mathrm{ad}(y)(x) \otimes v+ x \otimes y(v) \longmapsto (\mathrm{ad}(y)(x))(v)+x (y (v))=y( x (v)),$$ using the definition of representation of a Lie algebra.

Comment: Cool, that makes a lot of sense!