# Why must the tensor product of the adjoint representation with any arbitrary nontrivial representation D contain D for any Lie group?

Tags: lie-algebras

In Howard Georgi's book *Lie Algebras In Particle Physics*, it is claimed in Problem 12.C. that *for any Lie group, the tensor product of the adjoint representation with any arbitrary nontrivial representation D must contain D*.

I cannot figure out why it is so. I found a similar question [For the adjoint  and any nontrivial representation , why is  in ⊗?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713412/for-the-adjoint-a-and-any-nontrivial-representation-r-why-is-r-in-r-oti) But I don't understand the last part *It follows ...* in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The categories mentioned in that example are semi-simple, implying that every surjection $M \to N$ has a right inverse, so that $N$ is isomorphic to a subobject of $M$. For a compact Lie group, its category of finite-dimensional representations is semi-simple thanks to the fact that each such representation carries an invariant positive-definite Hermitian form (which may be obtained by averaging over the group, just as in the case of finite groups).